# Split view equally Master Detail iOS13

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller, ios13, splitview

Apparently I'll go full Ubuntu by the end of the week and bin my iPhone.
iOS13 has come to my Xcode and I can't find a way to split screen equally Master and Detail view. All tutorials and guides refers to a previous iOS.

The code I tried in my `AppDelegate` is:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let split = window?.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController {
            split.delegate = self
            split.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
            split.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
            split.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.5
        }
        return true
    }
```

but the screen is still splitted 30-70 or whatever the default is.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out in iOS13 is `SceneDelegate` responsible for `UIWindow` so the code above should go in the `sceneDidBecomeActive` function in the SceneDelegate.